# javascript regular expressions removing extra p tags

Tags: javascript, regex

When I copy from Microsoft Word and paste it from a clipboard into contenteditable div tag extra markup code gets pasted.
Here is a link to test:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/hFAdk

The script doesn't remove the extra paragraphs tags. This is the regular expression that I am trying to add but it's not working.

```
<p[^>]*>[\s|&nbsp;]*<\/p>
```

**Input**:

Mauris adipiscing lacus

Phasellus iaculis iaculis

Pellentesque felis quam

**Output**:

Mauris adipiscing lacus

Phasellus iaculis iaculis

Pellentesque felis quam

**Desired output**:

Mauris adipiscing lacus

Phasellus iaculis iaculis

Pellentesque felis quam

Does anyone have any idea how to remove those extra p tags? :(

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: you want to remove all `<p></p>` use javascript regex, right?

Comment: Hey Tim, Just want to remove the empty tags and I tried adding the regex but is not working <p[^>]*>[\s|&nbsp;]*<\/p> here is a link to test: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/hFAdk

Comment: ahh.. `<p[^>]*>[\s|&nbsp;]*<\/p>` is not working in JS as it should be `/<p[^>]*>[\s|&nbsp;]*<\/p>/gi`

Comment: [relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1810460)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
/<(p)[^>]*?>(\s|(&nbsp;))*?<\/\1>/gi
```

demo: https://regex101.com/r/uKrux8/1

Comment: how and where do i added to this script ? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/hFAdk

Comment: Good Morning Tim, your regex and mine work fine by itself but when i added to my code is just do nothing. :(  I added this line of code but 
it might conflict with something else in the code. content = content.replace(/<(p)[^>]*?>(\s|(&nbsp;))*?<\/\1>/gi, " ");    codepen.io/anon/pen/hFAdk The problem is putting it together :(

Comment: Hey Tim, my friend Robert figuere out and the problem and it was the regular expression http://booden.net/ContentCleaner.aspx <[^\/>][^>]*>\s*<\/[^>]+> Thanks for your help :)